# Is const broken with std::views?

Tags: c++, constants, c++20, std-ranges

```
void foo(const auto& collection)
{
    *collection.begin() = 104;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> ints {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    foo(ints); // Error, as it should be
    foo(ints | std::views::all); // Compiles and modifies the vector. Why?
    return 0;
}
```

Why is constness of lvalue reference completely ignored if an argument of a function is of type `std::view`?

Edit:
If, as you wrote in the comments, const view reference is similar to const pointer in this context, why does the code not compile if the same function takes a view constructed from an rvalue object as an argument?

```
std::vector<int> getVec()
{
    return std::vector{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
}

void foo(const auto& collection)
{
    *collection.begin() = 104; // Error: assignment of read-only location
}

int main()
{
    foo(getVec() | std::views::all); // Nope!
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I assume this is no different than `const std::span<int>` vs `std::span<const int>`.

Comment: It's for the same reason why if you have an `int *p;` a `const` reference to it still allows you to modify `*p`.

Comment: `const` is shallow; it's not transitive.  (I wish there was a transitive `deep_const`.)

Comment: @Eljay related: there is the experimental "[`propagate_const`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/propagate_const)" for pointers and pointer-like objects.

Comment: Standard views are [totally broken](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qv29fo9sUjY).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Views, despite the name, need not be non-modifiable. In general, how a class that represents a sequence of contained objects propagates `const` depends on what class gets used. And that's where things get weird.

See, the return type of `views::all(e)` [*changes* depending on exactly what `e` is](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/all_view). If `e` is a glvalue (and is not itself a view), then it returns a `ref_view` of the range denoted by `e`. `ref_view` behaves as if it [stores a pointer to the range it is given](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/ref_view). Of course, if you have an `R*` member of a class, the `const` equivalent of that is `R * const`, not `R const*`. So `ref_view` cannot propagate `const` to the contained range.

However, if `e` is a prvalue (and again is not a view), then what `all` returns is an `owning_view`. [This object actually *stores a copy* of `e` (well, it moves from it) as a member](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/owning_view). This means that when you get a `const owning_view`, that `const` is propagated to that member. And since `const vector<T>` *does* propagate `const`, so too will a `views::all(e)` of a prvalue of `vector`.

Comment: I was going to hold my tongue but ...  "`owning_view`" was not part of the original design. Previously, you couldn't use the adaptors on a temporary container. The existence of "`owning_view`" muddies the design and contributes to this confusion. I'm sad it was ever added.

Comment: The design got muddled as soon as we got `views::single`. `owning_view` is simply a safer and far more efficient way to spell `views::single | views::join`.